# Putting a time restraint on the users input

Tags: c, input

I am trying to create a C program which will create a wordsearch and then give the user a time to complete it in and then the program will output a message accordingly. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to ask the user for input while counting down. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hint: you need multiple threads to do this

Comment: hint: use signal ...

Comment: Some sample code and examples of things you tried would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the user input method it's own thread, a child of the main thread. Use wait in the main thread and then end the child thread when the wait is over.  Let us know if you have questions on how to create threads or how to use mutex to keep data secure.